# Show that the entries of a matrix are:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

For a regression model $y=\beta x$ (note there is no intercept term), show that entries of the matrix $\bf{H} = \bf{X}[\bf{X'}\bf{X}]^{-1}\bf{X'}$
are $h_{ij} = \frac{x_{i}x_{j}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}$.

Since there is no intercept term, the first column of $\bf{X}$ is all zeroes, and so $\bf{X}$ is of the form
 \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & x_{1}     \\
       0 & x_{2}    \\
       \vdots & \vdots  \\
       0 & x_{n}    \\
     \end{bmatrix}

I'm not sure how to proceed since it seems that $[\bf{X'}\bf{X}] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and so is singular.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Like you say, $X^TX$ is singular and you'll need to seek clarification what the notation $M^{-1}$ signifies for singular matrices. One reasonable interpretation is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Comment: Well, it is a proof about the hat matrix used in statistics, I'll add some more context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no intercept term, you shouldn't have a column of zeros.

The matrix equation is $\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix} = \beta \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}$, so $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}$.